# Загадка в Entity Framework 6.4.4

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Продвигаюсь в изучении сего фреймворка и столкнулся с интересной ситуацией.

Использую подход **Database first**. Автоматически был сгенерирован класс в соответствии с моей БД:

```
public partial class LibraryContex : DbContext
```

Я использую WinForms для графического представления содержимого, поэтому пытаюсь сделать следующее:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (LibraryContex db = new LibraryContex())
            {
                var authors = db.Authors;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = authors.Select(a => new { a.LastName, a.FirstName, a.Books.Count }).ToList();
                var author = db.Authors.FirstOrDefault();
                author.FirstName = "Имя";
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Из контекста, вероятно, все и так понятно(у первого выбранного автора изменяю имя и синхронизирую эти изменения с БД).

Но как только я хочу использовать

`var author = db.Authors.LastOrDefault();` вместо `var author = db.Authors.FirstOrDefault();`
мне передают привет:

**System.NotSupportedException: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'WindowsFormsApp_EntityFramework_1.Author LastOrDefaultAuthor' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."**

Расскажите почему нельзя использовать `db.Authors.LastOrDefault();`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы пишете одно, а показываете нам другое. Нет такого метода `LastOrDefaultAuthor`

Comment: @tym32167 добавил подтверждение скрином

Comment: Какого автора вы хотите этим получить? Последнего автора по какому принципу сортировки?

Comment: @tym32167 я хочу методом LastOrDefault() получить последнего автора из последовательности без какой-либо сортировки

Comment: тогда вам скорее всего надо всю коллекцию сначала в память загрузить. Типа `var author = db.Authors.ToList().LastOrDefault();`, хотя у меня есть сомнения в полезности такого эксперимента.

Comment: @tym32167 если я загружу в память всю коллекцию - работает. Но мое не понимание в том, почему метод FirstOrDefault() отрабатывает без загрузки в память, а LastOrDefault() требуется загрузка?

Comment: а как бы выглядел такой SQL запрос?

Comment: `.OrderByDescending().FirstOrDefault()` ?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten тут дело не в том, как достать последний, а разобраться в причинах исключения этой ситуации

Comment: @tym32167 если говорить про FirstOrDefault(), то он транслируется в    
```SELECT TOP (1) ``` ну и дальше источник данных и т.д. Про LastOrDefault() не смог найти инфу.

Comment: Ну так я про то же. Это может быть причиной, почему first работает, а last нет.